# Dynamically Create Links That Correspond to Keys in a JSON file and when Clicked Extract the data related to that key

Tags: javascript, html, json

OK, that's a long-winded title. Hope it makes sense. Let me try and clarify:

Let's say I have JSON file like this:

```
{
  "Bob Smith": {
    "born": "Decemeber 1, 1980",
    "died": null,
    "spouse": "Mary Smith",
    "parents": {
      "mother": "Jane Smith",
      "father": "Bill Smith"
    }
  }
}
```

The first thing I would do is list all the names found in the JSON file, or top level keys, ie Bob Smith. Then, that name would be a link that when click would load the data for that person into a specified element using AJAX. So if I click Bob Smith's name, his details appear in the document using AJAX.

I'm not sure how to do that. Normally with JSON we pass in a file or url to retrieve the data from. I guess what I need to do is something along the lines of (pseudo code):

```
get data from data.json at the specified key
```

or: `data.json/the key being clicked`

**EDIT: Added some starting code**

This is an example of the first step. So I would pull all the family member names into my HTML file using AJAX first, then the idea would be to use each key (ie the top level key for the family member's name) as a link that when clicked would load their corresponding data into the document:

```
function getAllFamilyMembers(data) {
  var xhttp, jsonData, parsedData;

  // check that we have access to XMLHttpRequest
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

     // get the data returned from the request...
     jsonData = this.responseText;
     // ...and parse it
     parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonData);

     console.log(parsedData);

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", data, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

getAllFamilyMembers('data.json');
```

I imagine this is something really simple that JS devs do all the time but I don't know how it's done. Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this in the context of a web application? Are you trying to write a script in js to accomplish this? If so, do you have some initial code that you can post?

Comment: it would be good if you can show the expected result(links)

Comment: An alternate option is to have all of the data read in to the HTML page, but just hide the persons information, then when a user clicks on the name, it will show their personal info without making another ajax request.

Comment: @RyanMc, it is working for you ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I havent had much time to work in this, was just a side project. Some of it works but doesnt quite do what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this `json`:

```
{
  "Bob Smith": {
    "born": "Decemeber 1, 1980",
    "died": null,
    "spouse": "Mary Smith",
    "parents": {
      "mother": "Jane Smith",
      "father": "Bill Smith"
    }
  }
}
```

You have to get all `keys`, like `Bob Smith` and create `hyperlinks` for each one of them. When you click a `hyperlink` you need to bind an event handler, where you can send `ajax` request.

```js
var json=[{
  "Bob Smith": {
    "born": "Decemeber 1, 1980",
    "died": null,
    "spouse": "Mary Smith",
    "parents": {
      "mother": "Jane Smith",
      "father": "Bill Smith"
    }
  }
},{
  "Ana Smith": {
    "born": "Decemeber 1, 1980",
    "died": null,
    "spouse": "Mary Smith",
    "parents": {
      "mother": "Jane Smith",
      "father": "Bill Smith"
    }
  }
}];
for(var i in json){
      var key=Object.keys(json[i])[0];
      var a=document.createElement('a');
      a.href=key;
      a.innerHTML=key;
      document.querySelector('body').appendChild(a);
}
var hyperlinks=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i=0;i<hyperlinks.length;i++){
  hyperlinks[i].onclick=function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var href=this.getAttribute('href');
     alert(href);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. One thing, I don't want to use jquery. Also, why do you wrap the JSON in an array?

Comment: I assumed that you have more objects in json.

Comment: Do you have one single object ?

Comment: Right, of course. They would need to be wrapped in an array. Thanks

Comment: No I would have numerous objects. It makes sense now

Comment: Do you want to declare event with javascript,not jquery ?

Comment: @RyanMc, I updated answer with full javascript code.